# Setting CSS upon mouse move does not work with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code, which makes an absolutely positioned box follow the mouse cursor:

```
  $(document).mousemove( function(e) {

    $(".wordbox").css({
      top: "calc(" + e.pageY + "px - 0.8em)",
      left: e.pageX
    }); 

  });
```

It works fine on its own, but when used in combination with Bootstrap 3 CSS, it does not work.

What could be the reason for this? Is Bootstrap somehow overriding these styles?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: I don't work with bootstrap but what if you change the class name to some random and unique name?

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://codepen.io/medinasod/pen/gPvMgy. Are you also using Bootstrap JS?

Comment: I see now that it's not a problem with Bootstrap, it's a problem with the absolute positioning.

Bootstrap adds a style to a parent element that makes the element position itself relative to this parent element, so my mouse-following box appears further down on the page.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Bootstrap introduced a positioned style to a parent element of the cursor-following box.

I solved the issue by appending the box at the body of the document, instead of nested inside the document that created it.